# Get rid of checking len(list) and call functions with/without args

Tags: python

I've got a list, smth like this
['func1', parm1]
or
['func2']

In some cases, there is no second element in the list. The method supposed to call has **kwargs argument, like def func1(self, **kwargs)

My current code is

```
cmd = matrix[i][0]
value = None
len_matrix = len(matrix[i])
if len_matrix > 1:
    value = matrix[i][1]
method = getattr(obj, cmd)
if len_matrix > 1:
    method(x=value)
else:
    method()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pop(0)` on the list to extract the first parameter (the function name). This mutates the list so it will just contain the arguments (if any).

```
def example(a="a", b="b"):
    return a, b


cmd = ["example", "arg_a", "arg_b"]

def caller(args):
    func_name = args.pop(0)
    func = globals()[func_name]
    return func(*args)

caller(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will improve readability, but you can achieve this by creating your kwargs dictionary dynamically.

```
getattr(obj, matrix[i][0])(**({"x": matrix[i][1]} if len(matrix[i]) > 1 else {}))
```

If you possibly have more arguments you could extend that more or less easily:

```
arg_names = "xyzabc"
getattr(obj, matrix[i][0])(**{
    arg_names[it]: val for it, val in enumerate(matrix[i][1:])
})
```

Obviously you could also use `arg_names[it - 1]: matrix[i][it] for it in range(1, len(matrix[i]))`

Hope that helped.